# Nuxt ignores proxy.pathRewrite when `yarn generate`

Tags: nuxt.js, yarnpkg

I use inside `nuxt.config.js`:

```
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    'cookie-universal-nuxt',
    'nuxt-vue-select'
  ],
  axios: {
    proxy: true,
    credentials: false,
    baseURL: 'https://api.example.com'
  },
  proxy: {
    '/api/': { target: 'https://api.example.com', pathRewrite: {'^/api/': ''} }
  },
```

unfortunately if I deploy webapp with `yarn generate` it's using `https://example.com/api/...` and ignoring pathRewrite rules into `https://api.example.com/...`.

how to solve it?

Answer (score 4):

The problem with yarn generate ist, that it is used for static hosting where you don't have your server side proxy. The only workaround I found was writing your own "pathRewrite"  logic in an axios OnRequest interceptor, so that it behaves similary to the proxy "pathRewrite".

plugin/axios.js

```
const prod = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production";
const prefix = "/api/";

export default function({ $axios }) {
  
  $axios.onRequest(config => {
    
    // The proxy is disabled in prod mode => write own rewritePath here
    if (prod && config.url.startsWith(prefix)) {
      config.url = config.url.replace(prefix, process.env.API_BASEURL);
    }

    return config;
  });
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
 /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  env:{
   API_BASEURL:'https://api.example.com'
  },
  plugins:[
    '~/plugins/axios.js'
  ],
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    "@nuxtjs/proxy",
  ],
  axios: {
    credentials: false,
  },
  proxy: {
    '/api/': { target: 'https://api.example.com', pathRewrite: {'^/api/': ''} }
  },
```

Comment: It can replace the url but can't finish the request due to CORS policy? How can you avoid that one?

Comment: Do you mean in production? Your backend has to send you the right cors header. E.g. "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://frontend.example".

Answer (score 3):

Currently only working workaround for this issue is avoiding using `yarn generate` and always use `yarn build; yarn start` on production.

however it's truly disappointing workaround and sometimes even impossible to use (if one hosting doesn't provide explicit support for node webapps).

Has anyone else found a better solution?